# Is it possible for one view in my MVC 3 application to not use the _Layout.cshtml master page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've created a View that *I don't* want to inherit from the _Layout.cshtml, seems pretty intuitive but I just can't seem to figure out how to avoid using it?

Can I somehow put conditional logic into the _Layout.cshtml or is there another way?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the view

```
@model YourModelClass

@{
    Layout = null;
}
```